# my folder changed it's lowercase to uppercase

Tags: git, github

I have this project which I've pushing it to github for the last couple month.

And I've noticed that one of my folders name changed it's name... I mean basically it didn't change much but bit more like changed from `components`  to 
 `Components`, and that really giving me hard-time deploying it cloud.

So here in VSCode the foler name is **component**.

[image]

Then committed it and pushed it to github and it beccame **Components** with first name become **capital-letter**

[image]

So, what caused that and how to solve?   thanks in advane.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17683458/1256452 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53057379/1256452 (and, related, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41154015/1256452)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably renamed the folder locally, and Git is unaware of the changes because it's configured to ignorecase. You can set `core.ignorecase` to be `true`:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

and you can force Git to accept the changes:

```
git mv components tmp && git mv tmp Components
```

Comment: `git mv components tmp && git mv tmp Components`  is  ginving `fatal: bad source, source=components, destination=tmp`

Comment: @Lafoune Maybe it's "Components" as the first argument instead, not sure why you're getting this.

Comment: `core.ignorecase` is set locally in every repository: when Git creates a repository, it tests how the system behaves, and then sets `core.ignorecase` locally to `true` if the underlying file system treats file names as "the same" even if they differ in case. This means that setting it globally (`git config --global`) has no effect: the local setting continues to override the global one. In general it's not wise to override Git's computed settings: they tell Git what your computer does, and if you have them lie to Git, Git may mistakenly do things that you wouldn't want.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have to switch back to command-line for this `git mv`, considering VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020) now have:

> ### [Git: Rename](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d9a6977d8a5d2c0f9f0fb28227ac4a022d558c3b/release-notes/v1_52.md#git-rename)
>
> There's a new `Git: Rename` command which lets you perform a git mv command from the VS Code UI.