# Github branch naming convention solution

Tags: git, github

I manage a Github Oraganization (private and enterprise). I am looking for a solution to limit branches names in all repos under my organization. (For example: brach can contain only lower case letters and hyphen).

I know that it can be achieved through branch protection rule in each repository, but I am not willing to go over 500 repositories and add the same protection rule.

Is there any solution from Github? Or any open source tool that can achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54222881/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+branch+protection+rule+organisation

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35659680/1725151